# “the tears rolled off the side of his face before they reached his lips”：should 'could reach' be used instead？

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am reading a book with this sentence and it confuses me...

> He was crying again, a soft and quiet cry, and because his head was back, the tears rolled off the side of his face before they reached his lips.

This sentence describe a man with ALS.

So, here's my questions:

- Did the tears finally reach his lips?
- If the tears ***didn't*** reach the lips, then why didn't the author use
  the modal (expressing counterfactual) construction after 'before'？**

Comment: Because "before they **could** reach his lips" would suggest that reaching his lips was the tears' *goal*.

Comment: I don't see it being any more problematic than "He died before his 95th birthday" or "We left the motorway before Leeds". Do you think using "before" is wrong, or do you just want to know if the modal would be valid?

Comment: @StuartF To be fair to OP, **before** with a locative complement ("Leeds") is different than **before** with a finite clausal complement; what if it said "...died before he celebrated his 95th birthday"? There, **could celebrate** would work.

Comment: It would be clearer if it used the word **but** instead of **and**:   **but** because his head was back, the tears rolled off the side of his face before they reached his lips.

Answer (score 1):

The point you make is logical, but English often takes liberties to simplify time- or possibility-constraints in verb constructions.  [Anne McCaffrey in 'Dragonquest'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22before+they+reached+the+ground%22&sca_esv=562712696&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=ygX3ZPioEaKdhbIPzaafoAg&ved=0ahUKEwj4teegpJOBAxWiTkEAHU3TB4QQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22before+they+reached+the+ground%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiICJiZWZvcmUgdGhleSByZWFjaGVkIHRoZSBncm91bmQiSOxVUJYGWN9QcAF4AJABAJgBc6ABqxCqAQQyNi4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIKEAAYRxjWBBiwA8ICChAAGIoFGLADGEPCAggQABiKBRiRAsICBRAAGIAEwgIFEC4YgATCAgsQLhiABBixAxiDAcICCxAuGIAEGMcBGK8BwgIUEC4YgAQYlwUY3AQY3gQY4ATYAQHCAgYQABgWGB7CAggQABgWGB4YCsICCBAAGIoFGIYDwgIHEC4YDRiABMICCBAAGBYYHhgPwgIIEAAYCBgeGA3CAhYQLhgNGIAEGJcFGNwEGN4EGOAE2AEB4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGCroGBggBEAEYFA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) has:

> - *The dragonriders took to the skies and their flying dragons swirled in space, belching flames that destroyed the strands before they
>   reached the ground.*

And [IXL: Maths and English Practice](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22before+they+reach+the+ground%22+meteors&sca_esv=562712696&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=9AX3ZLPfLom6hbIP0O6DUA&ved=0ahUKEwizqYi1pJOBAxUJXUEAHVD3AAoQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22before+they+reach+the+ground%22+meteors&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiJiJiZWZvcmUgdGhleSByZWFjaCB0aGUgZ3JvdW5kIiBtZXRlb3JzMgUQIRigATIIECEYFhgeGB1I4jxQpwZYhzlwAXgAkAEAmAFqoAGBB6oBAzkuMrgBA8gBAPgBAcICCBAhGKABGMMEwgIGEAAYFhgewgIIEAAYigUYhgPCAgcQIRigARgKwgIEECEYFeIDBBgBIEGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) has

> - *Usually, meteors burn up before they reach the ground.*

[Smithsonian Magazine](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/blogs/national-museum-of-natural-history/2022/02/10/from-clouds-to-currents-what-is-the-water-cycle/) has

> - *Water droplets might pass through air so unsaturated that they evaporate before they reach the ground.*

The illogical use of what seems a contradictory verb form is often quite idiomatic where clarity isn't compromised. Using 'could' or 'can' remains an acceptable alternative.

And in fact (this prompted by a comment from Paul Tanenbaum), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/before#google_vignette)
(sense [2] below) even cater for this use of *before* (before X happens = before X can happen):

> **be‧fore** ... [conjunction]
>
> ```
>   [1] earlier than a particular event or action
> ```
>
> - *Say goodbye before you go*.
>
> [2] so that something does not or cannot happen
>
> - *Put that money somewhere safe before it gets stolen.*
> - *That dog ought to be destroyed before it attacks any more children.*
> - [“*Johnny, stop swinging that axe before you kill someone!*”] [PaulTanenbaum]

Paul's example is certainly totally idiomatic, and (like the 'safe' example, where 'can' doesn't work) hard to paraphrase using a more felicitous verb phrase. A nice example.

Comment: “Johnny, stop swinging that axe before you kill someone!”

Comment: Be my guest!  :-)

Comment: Johnny threw the axe **and** it struck a branch before it reached someone.  Is or is not Johnny guilty of manslaughter?

Comment: @TimRonadifferentdevice If he's on trial for manslaughter, it presumably hit the victim after striking the branch. Context removes the ambiguity.

Comment: Note that the "so that ... doesn't happen" sense is usually used in commands, not reported actions.

Comment: _Before_, since it can refer to the future, can be used as a counterfactual: _Get him out of here before the Dean sees him!; We got him out before the Dean saw him_

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Now I understand why ‘before’ is used like this. I was really confused by this sentence at first because it comes from a very good writer.

Comment: But I wonder as native speakers, do you think the word off in roll off implies that the tears left the cheeks and did not reach the lips? Or is it just illustrating the sliding motion of tears.

Comment: Context demands they left his face, not reaching as far as the lips. But 'roll off [a surface]' certainly defaults to a leaving of the surface ('rolled off the table'). The metaphorical broadening ('rolled off the assembly line') ditto. But the electronics usage (see [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roll-off#google_vignette)) is intransitive. As is the snooker usage ('Did you see the white roll off there?')